# A word for something that is impossible to be sure of?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, vocabulary, obscure-terms

A **noun** for something that you cannot prove; something you can never be sure of actually happening/being real?

Comment: Hi, thanks for visting the EL&U. Please click throhg on the [single-word-requests tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) and read up on the Tag info and edit your question to include the required information and sample sentence.

Comment: I posted an answer with the word "unknown", as it's listed as a noun in all dictionaries. Then I realised that an unknown may become known in the future, so I deleted my answer. However the other answers also allow for discovery, which is a possibility you excluded in your request, "something you can never be sure of actually happening/being real"

Comment: @Zebrafish I've voted to put this question on hold for lack of context, but if you wanted to push your answer to include the *never* part, "(an) unknowable" could be pressed into service as a noun.

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, I first thought of "unknowable", I was going to give it as an answer with the caveat that it's only listed in one online dictionary as a noun. I went with "unknown" given that it's in every dictionary, except I lost sight of the actual question, haha.

Answer (score 1):

One of the many synonymous is **uncertainty**.

Comment: Should've clarified that I'm looking for a noun, sorry.

Comment: Edited so the word is now a noun.

Comment: Thanks man, with your help - "practical uncertainty" is probably what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to think **incertitude** is up to the task without the bulky feeling.

[Definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incertitude?src=search-dict-hed)

> incertitude
>
> noun
>
> in·​cer·​ti·​tude | (ˌ)in-ˈsər-tə-ˌtüd,  -ˌtyüd\
>
> Definition of incertitude
>
> : UNCERTAINTY:
>
> a : absence of assurance or confidence : DOUBT
>
> b : the quality or state of being unstable or insecure

Comment: Hi Jackspace, welcome to EL&U. This isn't a bad start, but it's too short: the system has flagged it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. Can I suggest you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition of *incertitude* (linked to the source) and why it's the best fit? For further guidance, see [answer]. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider ***inscrutability***, which is the noun form of *inscrutable*:

> Impossible to understand or interpret.
>   <sub>[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inscrutable)</sub>

It's mostly used to describe people that are difficult to understand, but it can be applied generally as well. Consider this second definition source:

> the quality of being impossible to investigate
>   *“the **inscrutability** of the future”*
>   <sub>[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/inscrutability)</sub>